# Корректно ли после дополнения закрывать / открывать снова txt файл из памяти?

Tags: android, запись

По нажатии кнопки в файл последовательно пишется строка текста, затем заново открывается и читается весь файл чтобы обновить textEdit. Всего таких запросов около 300 в сутки, корректно ли так делать в плане количества чтения/записи в память телефона?

```
private void writeToFile(String eventDescription) { 
        File historyFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "/History.txt");
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(historyFile, true);
            writer.append(eventDescription).append("\r\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void readFileInAppDir() {  //вывод txt из папки приложения файла в textEdit
        File historyFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "/History.txt");
        if (historyFile.exists()) { //проверка существует ли
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            try { //чтение и вывод
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(historyFile));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
            EditText tv = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            tv.setText(text.toString());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FILE DOESN'T EXIST!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: а зачем заново читать файл, если нужный текст и так уже есть в памяти?

Comment: нужный текст - весь файл, а записывается в конкретный момент только одна строка

Comment: я имею в виду, в едиттекст уже ведь есть текст, можно просто добавить к этому же тексту еще одну строку, не считывая заново весь файл. Но вообще, если вопрос об износе флеш-носителя, то чтение на износ никак не влияет, а 300 запросов на запись в день это ни о чем (если файл не особо огромных размеров). Если же вопрос о том, оптимально ли так делать, то тут желательно больше информации о приложении.

Comment: Приложение грубо говоря - один экран, 6 кнопок, по нажатии на каждую в файл пишется время нажатия. Весь текст файла тут же выводится на editText. файл лежит либо в корне приложения, в папке для файлов, либо в документах либо на сд карте, пока не определился. Спасибо за информацию!